# Mixpanel using Google Tag Manager and React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-tag-manager, mixpanel

I am trying to implement Mixpanel with my React App using Google Tag Manager. I have successfully integrated it using GTM but I have trouble with mixpanel always being undefined on reload. I am using CDN for it.

If I go onto some other page and come back to the page where I am using Mixpanel, there's no error. So I diagnosed that as it is an asynchronous operation it takes some time to load mixpanel in my app. So I tried using the `useEffect` hook and `useState` but it failed to solve my problem.

Below is my code:

```js
const [mixpanelLoad, setMixpanelLoad] = useState(false);

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('IN USEEFFECT');
    console.log(mixpanel);
    if (mixpanel) {
    // It never comes here on first reload
      setMixpanelLoad(true);
      console.log('MIXPANEL LOADED');
    }
    if (mixpanelLoad) {
    // thus it never does the tracking 
      console.log('DOING TRACKING');
      mixpanel.track('Track Bill Page');
    }
  }, [mixpanelLoad]);
```

On first reload it always says that mixpanel is undefined.

I am using CDN so I don't have to use any mixpanel library.

Comment: Where is `mixpanel` imported from?

Comment: It is coming from CDN from google tag manager. I don't have to import anything

Comment: You mentioned `asynchronous operation`, is there some initialization function?

Comment: Yes mixpanel  itself is a async

Answer (score 0):

Certain methods/features can only be used after the Mixpanel library has [finished loading](https://developer.mixpanel.com/docs/javascript-full-api-reference#mixpanelget_distinct_id). `init()` has a loaded function available to handle this automatically -

```
mixpanel.init('YOUR PROJECT TOKEN', {
    loaded: function(mixpanel) {
        distinct_id = mixpanel.get_distinct_id();
    }
});
```

Comment: You are wrong that's when we are using NPM library but I am not using NPM according to the docs of mixpanel.

Comment: I understand but from where `mixpanel` will get imported from? Can you share the library initialization code in <script>?

Comment: I can't paste the link over here but here is the URL from where you can get the script

(https://shrib.com/#Dash2j7MdQ2) [1]